4x4 keypad scanning with AVR and displaying results to LEDs, issues with hardware
trying to program a 4x4 keypad to display hex value on the board I have. any time I output to the board every, it defaults to 0xFF.
So far ive tried addling longer delays between key pressed and cleaned up the scanning alorithim but It has not really helped. I believe on each Column cycle I may not be scanning correctly. Simulation works fine and references the correct value in flash so it has to be something else in the way ive configured it.
type he;*****************************************************
; Define variables.
.def  temp  = r16
.equ SP = 0xDF
.equ IO = 0xFF
.equ ROW_MASK = 0x0f        //DEFINING MASKS FOR ROW
.equ COL_MASK = 0xf0        //DEFINING MASKS FOR COL
.def colarray = r25
.def kparray = r24

LDI ZH, high(array << 1)
LDI ZL, low(array << 1)
mov kparray, r30
LDI ZH, high(col << 1)
LDI ZL, low(col << 1)
mov colarray, r30           

; Reset Vector.
reset:
   rjmp start

;***********************************************************
; This program reads a single number from the keypad.
;***********************************************************
; Program starts here after Reset
start:
    LDI  TEMP,  SP      ; Init Stack pointer
    OUT  0x3D,  TEMP

    CALL Init           ; Initialise the system.

loop:       
    ; Get a single key from the keypad and return it in R16 (temp)
    CALL ReadKey      

    ; Once the key has been recieved, put it on the PORTB leds.             
    CALL Display
    
    RJMP     loop           ; Do all again - You don't need to reinitialize

;************************************************************************
;
Init:
; uses:    R16
; returns: nothing
;
; Initialise the 16-key keypad connected to Port C
; This assumes that a 16-key alpha numeric keypad is connected to
; Port C as follows (see keypad data):
; Keypad   Function                      J2 pin
;  1      Row 1, Keys 1, 2, 3, A       1   PC0
;  2      Row 2, Keys 4, 5, 6, B       2   PC1
;  3      Row 3, Keys 7, 8, 9, C       3   PC2
;  4      Row 4, Keys *, 0, #, D       4   PC3
;  5      Column 1, Keys 1, 4, 7, *    5   PC4
;  6      Column 2, Keys 2, 5, 8, 0    6   PC5
;  7      Column 3, Keys 3, 6, 9, #    7   PC6
;  7      Column 4, Keys A, B, C, D    8   PC7

    ; Set the pull-up resistor values on PORTC.


    LDI R20, 0xF0
    ldi r21, 0x0F
    ldi r22, 0xff
    
    out ddrb, r22
    out ddrc, r20           //mapping port C to scan for keypad - PB0-3 Set up as inputs to scan for button presses
    out portc, r21
    
    clr r20
    clr r21
    clr r23
    mov r30, colarray
    RET 

;************************************************************************
;
; ReadKey - Read a single digit from the keypad and store in TEMP
; Uses:  R16 (Temp)
; Returns: Temp
;
 ReadKey:
lpm r18, Z
in r19, PORTC
andi r19, ROW_MASK
com r18
andi r18, COL_MASK
or r19, r18
OUT PORTC, R19
//call readkey and scan each row for any input 
 call ReadKP
//SHIFT TO NEXT COLUMN

ColShift:

cpi r18, 0x70
breq Oreset
inc r30

rjmp ReadKey

Oreset:
    mov r30, r25   
    rjmp ReadKey    

;
;********************************************************************
; ReadKP will determine which key is pressed and return that key in Temp
; The design of the keypad is such that each row is normally pulled high
; by the internal pullups that are enabled at init time
;
; When a key is pressed contact is made between the corresponding row and column.
; To determine which key is pressed each column is forced low in turn
; and software tests which row has been pulled low at micro input pins
;
; To avoid contact bounce the program must include a delay to allow
; the signals time to settle
;
ReadKP:
    IN R20, PINC        //take input from PINC
    ANDI R20, ROW_MASK  //AND instruction and ROW_MASK to determine if any key has been pressed 
    CPI R20, ROW_MASK   //compare value in r20 with ROW_MASK to see if any rows have been pulled low, if not > go to column shift and continue cycling
    BREQ ColShift       //branch instruction

    IN R20, PINC        //keypad detected, as one input pulled low
    CALL DELAY          //call delay for debouncing routine
    IN R21, PINC        //taking keypad input as befoer to make sure it is correct,
    CP R20, R21         //compare values of both before delay and after delay - if they match up then go to output value to temp
    BREQ DISPLAY        // GO TO DISPLAY TO DISPLAY VALUE IN R20
    RET                 //If key changed between then return back to scanning columns

;************************************************************************
;
; Takes whatever is in the Temp register and outputs it to the LEDs
Display:

        COM R20         //invert bits to reference key talble correctly
        MOV ZL, kparray //Reference keytable in memory
        ADD ZL, R20     //Add ZL from r20 to reference key table
        LPM R16, Z  //load from program memory the correct value
        OUT PortB, R16  //output value to PORTB
        
        RJMP Oreset     //go back to oreset and continue to scan columns
;*************************************
;
; Delay routine
;
; this has an inner loop and an outer loop. The delay is approximately
; equal to 256*256*number of inner loop instruction cycles.
; You can vary this by changing the initial values in the accumulator.
; If you need a much longer delay change one of the loop counters
; to a 16-bit register such as X or Y.
;
;*************************************
Delay:
    PUSH R16            ; Save R16 and 17 as we're going to use them
    PUSH R17            ; as loop counters
    PUSH R0         ; we'll also use R0 as a zero value
    CLR R0
    CLR R16         ; Init inner counter
    CLR R17         ; and outer counter
L1: 
    DEC R16         ; Counts down from 0 to FF to 0
    CPSE R16, R0    ; equal to zero?
    RJMP L1         ; If not, do it again
    CLR R16         ; reinit inner counter
L2: 
    DEC R17
    CPSE R17, R0    ; Is it zero yet?
    RJMP L1         ; back to inner counter

    POP R0          ; Done, clean up and return
    POP R17
    POP R16
    RET






Col:
    .DB 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80  
        
array:
            
            .db 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255  
            .db 255, 0x01,0x02, 255, 0x07, 255, 255, 255, 0x2A, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255
            .db 255, 0x02, 0x05, 255, 0x08, 255, 255, 255, 0x00, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255
            .db 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255   //63

            .db 255, 0x03, 0x06, 255, 0x09, 255, 255, 255, 0x23, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255  
            .db 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255
            .db 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255
            .db 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255  //126

            .db 255, 0x0A, 0x0B, 255, 0x0C, 255, 255, 255, 0x0D, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255  
            .db 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255
            .db 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255
            .db 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255
            
            .db 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255  
            .db 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255
            .db 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255 //
            .db 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255

re


I don't know what "defaults to 0xFF" means.  Are you able to read the keypad?  Can you force values into the LEDs?

whenever a key is pressed, regardless of location on the keypad all the LEDs light up. there are 256 values in the keytable for invalid presses, most of them 0xFF for invalid combinations. I can read the keypad by forcing a value into PORTB if any button is pressed.

Please add a schematic of your project. -- And while you're [edit]ing, please make your source better readable, the missing and inconsistent indentation makes it hard to read.

Your Init routine is setting the low-order 4 bits of PORTC to inputs, and the high-order 4 bits as outputs.  I believe you want to write 0 to DDRC, and you shouldn't write anything to PORTC if it is all inputs.

the upper nibble bits correspond to output rows (columns) and the lower bits correspond to inputs (rows) the board I'm using has portc bits hardwired onto the LEDs of PORTB

Please add a schematic to your question. I will not try to dive deep into your (hard to read) code to assume something that might not be there.
